# How can I see the contents of a PVC in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I'm having a pain point with Kubernetes and I hope someone can help me out. I'm trying to see the contents of a PVC (Persistent Volume Claim), but it seems that the only way to do so is to mount the PVC into a container and check what's inside.

As you can imagine, this is quite cumbersome and not very practical. I was wondering if there are any tools or solutions that could make this process easier?

I've searched around but haven't found anything yet. If anyone has any ideas or suggestions, please let me know! I'm eager to hear your thoughts and experiences.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in way to do this. To get around this, you would have to attach the disk to a container or VM and inspect its contents

You need to add the pvc to a pod and copy the files using kubectl cp or list the files using kubectl exec to check the contents of PVC.

A simpler way is to create an inspector POD to inspect the contents of PVC and clean up the pod easily as explained in this [blog](https://frank.sauerburger.io/2021/12/01/inspect-k8s-pvc.html) by Frank Sauerburger.